# Microsoft Test Manager - edit test result, through Manager or Tfs_Warehouse database?

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

We have a test result where one of the test steps has an attachment, and the name of this attachment creates problems for reporting due to non-Western European characters in the attachment name.

Is it possible to rename the file, attached to the test step details? If I cannot do this through Test Manager, can it be done directly in the Tfs_Warehouse database?

Here is where the attachment is, the offending name is circled in red:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no place to change through Microsoft Test Manager. And modify the original data in Tfs_Warehouse is also strongly not recommend.

If you just want to ignore the error for reporting, as a workaround you can delete the test run directly. Otherwise, you may have to change the file name in attachment locally and upload it.

Comment: Thanks, figured out pretty much the same. Was asked to avoid deletion of the test run and ended up modifying the path to make it shorter. Worked out well enough in the end.